# Controlling music playback on iOS with react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, react-native-sound

I used to have an app that would create a sprint workout playlist - it would start a song 30 seconds in, play 1 minute, then move to the next song. I'm looking to create something similar.

I want to access and play songs from the users built in music library. Would this be possible? What library or api would I need to use?

I've tried looking into MusicKit but I'm not seeing helpful stuff for react-native. I'm also considering the react-native-itunes library but was wondering if there is a more obvious or common approach, or possibly something already included with Expo that I'm unaware of.